# Exiting a console application when an Escape key is press

Tags: c#

Please could any one help me out, i want to customize my console program to exit only when the user press the Escape key on the keyboard. I appreciate your help.
C# console application.

Comment: Could you show us your programs code?

Comment: `Console.ReadKey()` ...

Comment: Do you want also to disable clicking on the RED exit button on the console window?

Comment: I don't think that duplicate covers the case of aborting the close if the user presses the CLOSE button on the console window. Let's wait sometime for an answer to my comment above

Comment: Looking at comments in the answer below, I should apologize to previous user that closed the app as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Try smth like this one

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{

         [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, uint uIDEnableItem, uint uEnable);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
        internal const UInt32 SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
        internal const UInt32 MF_ENABLED = 0x00000000;
        internal const UInt32 MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001;
        internal const UInt32 MF_DISABLED = 0x00000002;
        internal const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnableCloseButton(this, false);
        }

        public static void EnableCloseButton(IWin32Window window, bool bEnabled)
        {
            IntPtr hSystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(window.Handle, false);
            EnableMenuItem(hSystemMenu, SC_CLOSE, (uint)(MF_ENABLED | (bEnabled ? MF_ENABLED : MF_GRAYED)));
        }


    }
```

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-us/545f1768-8038-4f7a-9177-060913d6872f/disable-close-button-in-console-application-in-c)

Comment: Does this block pressing the CLOSE button from exiting the app? Please reread the question

Comment: Post variant to disable close button. But i don't suppose how you prevent pressing ctrl+alt+del and closing from there. It's better to run some service, which will start your application any time when it closes.

Comment: Nice link, not enough time to test that stuff. It seems that is pretty debated there.

Comment: However. also without a compiler to help, the keyword _this_ in a static method seems to be a clear error.

Comment: Thanks! but what i actually is not to disable the the close button is just something like this:

Comment: Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'Esc' to quit ");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to Continue ");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'Tab' to go back to Menu  ");

Comment: ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
            while (true)
            {
                keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();

                if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    do something
                }

Comment: else if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Tab)               
                
                else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    in here exit application

                }
            }

Comment: but the  other two buttons (the tab and Enter) are working fine but the Escape is  not working